# standard sql queries in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I do SQL queries in rails. For example if I want to take params from the users table in my database and match them against another table? Just need a starting ground. Really new to rails...

EDIT/

I'm not looking for a way to do raw SQL, I just want a way to use rails to harness my data (like how would a product selector work with categories, etc)

EDIT/

Basically, users are creating listings of items of things for sale and users (in their preferences pane) select the things that they want. I want to create a 'dashboard' that shows a list of items that other users have posted for sale that matches what they selected in their preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking about how you perform joins with other tables? Rails makes this very easy through associations. Take a look at [Rails Guides: ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks. I have a bunch of user preferences (favorite cars, favorite movie, etc) and I want to match them to listings of cars, movies for sale, etc. Want to find matches to their profile.

Comment: I don't know if this would work though because it's relying on a has_many and belongs_to relationship. Basically, users are creating listings of items of things for sale and users (in their preferences pane) select the things that they want. I want to create a 'dashboard' that shows a list of items that other users have posted for sale that matches what they selected in their preferences.